How can I build a NAS with file read latency of less than 100ms?
I know this may sound like an almost impossible goal.
I would like to see an average read delay of less than 100ms from my laptop to my NAS.
My prior knowledge is as follows.
When connecting a 5,400rpm HDD via SATA, the typical read delay is up to 20ms.
Even for modern NAS, the average HDD SMB read delay is as high as 1,500ms.

https://www.storagereview.com/en/review/synology-ds923-review

The restrictions are as follows:
I have used over 6TB of storage. An SSD NAS that supports this capacity cannot be built at a realistic cost that an individual can afford.
When using iSCSI, I cannot use Synology's convenient programs such as DS File or features such as DLNA. This is not the result I want.
My current environment is as follows.
Two WD Red Plus 10TB hard drives configured in RAID1 on DS213+ NAS for Reliability
The NAS is connected to the Wi-Fi router with 1GbE
Main clients are connected by Wi-Fi 6E 6GHz 160MHz channel
I can afford up to 3000 USD.
What changes will get me the results I want?

How are you measuring read latency? Does all the storage need to be at that latency all the time?  The wifi might be a cause of latency, so have you checked wireless vs wired latency?

Are you able to SSH into your NAS and perform tests locally? More specifically, are you able to test access to the files directly, so you can isolate disk access latency vs SMB and network latency? It would make sense to figure out the primary bottleneck before wasting time and money.

I question the restrictions of this post – you said you can't afford 6TB of SSD storage, but you also said you can afford up to $3000 USD, and that easily buys you eight 4TB EVO 870's for 32TB of storage, going by the USA prices I've found – even if you're limited to four disk bays and want a RAID1 across them (4TBx4/2), that's still 8TB of storage for $1400, well within your stated limits.

(That, and I'm really surprised by the SMB results you're getting. With my file server that I got off ebay for €300, accessing files via NFS over Wi-Fi 4 (Wireless-N) off a pair of second-hand WD10EZEX's, the average latency is just over 50 ms. Part of that might be the HDDs being 7200 rpm in my case, but part of that is certainly something weird happening in your network. Could it be that you have multiple clients fighting for I/O? If that's the case, it'll be really hard to avoid with HDDs.)

@Journeyman : My wireless latency is short enough to be negligible.

@Bob : My NAS can SSH, but However, complex tools are difficult to use by NAS CPU and my knowlege.

@grawity_u1686 : ... That's right. I can buy 4TB EVO 870's just 330USD in my country, and 4disk with RAID5 served reliabilty and high-performance.
I use only one client in my wired network and NAS service, My complaint was that it took a while to read 24MP JPEG photos and video browsing experience that wasn't the same as local.
